# How to update a dynamically added row values of a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that the rows are dynamically added using `javascript`:

```
<div class="bg-white p-3" id="IPCRTable"> 
      <div class="hotel pb-4 table-bordered"> 
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
          <table class="table" id="table" name="table">
           <thead>
              <tr class="table-active">
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Output <br>(A)</th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Success Indicators<br>(Targets + Measures)<br>(B)</th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Actual Accomplishments<br>(C)</th>
                <th scope="col" colspan="4">Rating<br>(D)
                  <table class="table table-borderless" id="rating">
                    <tr>
                      <td>Q</td>
                      <td>E</td>
                      <td>T</td>
                      <td>A</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Remarks<br>(E)</th>
                <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Action</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
            <tbody id = "tbody">
          <!-- to be filled by javascript-->
            </tbody>
          </table> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

here is the modal that adds values to the row that will be appended onto my table:

```
</div>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end align-items-center">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button" id="addheader" aria-pressed="true" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addHeader">ADD HEADER</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button" id="addtask" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" aria-pressed="true">ADD OUTPUTS/INDICATORS/ACCOMPLISHMENTS</button>
      <a href="Create_IPCR.php" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true">ADD SUB-HEADER</a>
    </div>
```

here is the javascript function that adds rows to my table,

```
function addRows(){
        var table = document.getElementById('tbody'),
            newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
            cell0 = newRow.insertCell(0),
            cell1 = newRow.insertCell(1),
            cell2 = newRow.insertCell(2),
            cell3 = newRow.insertCell(3),
            cell4 = newRow.insertCell(4),
            cell5 = newRow.insertCell(5),
            cell6 = newRow.insertCell(6),
            cell7 = newRow.insertCell(7),
            cell8 = newRow.insertCell(8),
            outputA = document.getElementById("outputA").value,
            indicatorB = document.getElementById("indicatorB").value,
            accomplishmentC = document.getElementById("accomplishmentC").value;

            cell0.innerHTML = outputA;
            cell1.innerHTML = indicatorB;
            cell2.innerHTML = accomplishmentC;
            cell3.innerHTML;
            cell4.innerHTML;
            cell5.innerHTML;
            cell6.innerHTML;
            cell7.innerHTML;
            cell8.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editData" aria-pressed="true" name="tdName" id="editModal"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="fas fa-comment"></span></a> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" name = "deletebtn" id="deletebtn" onclick= "deleteRow(this)"><span class="fas fa-trash" ></span></button>';
           
    };
```

as you can see from the function, there is a group of bootstrap buttons on `cell8` that are supposed to be able to edit, delete, and add a comment on the row (though im not really sure how to implement that, i will just figure it out next time)

I successfully made the delete button to work, but I'm having trouble making the edit button work. What's supposed to happen is when it is pressed, a modal would pop up and then it would take the users new value, after hitting the save changes button on the modal, its supposed to edit the data of that certain row without reloading the page.

this is the function for the edit button:

```
   function editRows(event, row){
        event.preventDefault();
        var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,
        outputA = document.getElementById("outputA").value,
        indicatorB = document.getElementById("indicatorB").value,
        accomplishmentC = document.getElementById("accomplishmentC").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("table"); // Identify table
          // Check if the row index is valid
     if (i >= 0 && i < table.rows.length) {
            var targetRow = table.rows[i]; // Gets the target row
            // Update the cells in the row with the new values
            targetRow.cell[0].innerHTML = outputA; 
            targetRow.cell[1].innerHTML = indicatorB;
            targetRow.cell[2].innerHTML = accomplishmentC; 
         } 
    };
```

this function doesn't work I'm completely frustrated because of it for days now. how can I make the edit button work?

Comment: `innerHTML; ` is incorrect. If it should stay empty you should use `innerHTML = '';`. Then use `textContent` which is faster and does not pose security issues. Instead of adding a button through `innerHTML` you should create it dynamically with `createElement` and append it to the cell.